# issue with using Mongoose.disconnect()

Tags: typescript, mongoose, disconnect

i have a disconnect function as below:

````
```
export function disconnectN(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve,_reject) => {
        if (!database) {
            return;
        }
        Mongoose.disconnect();
        console.log("  <databaseNorm.ts> Disconnected from database");
        return;
    });
}
```
````

However when i call it with :

```
`await disconnect();`
```

in my main module, it seems that program is going to a very long pause state and not continuing with my next lines.

I am new to typescript and concept of async/await and it is hard for me to understand it (used to structural programming).

I would appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: You never resolve, nor reject the promise.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed it to :export function disconnectR(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!database) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            Mongoose.disconnect(err => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("  <databaseRaw.ts> Disconnected from database");
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

Answer (score 0):

```
export function disconnect(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!database) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            Mongoose.disconnect(err => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("  <database.ts> Disconnected from database");
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.disconnect()` returns a promise, so you can simplify your function to:

```
export function disconnect(): Promise<void> {
    if(!database)
        return Promise.resolve();
    return Mongoose.disconnect().then(() => console.log("  <database.ts> Disconnected from database"));
}
```